# Spring integration - File : how to define fixed-rate attribute value during run time

Tags: spring-integration

currently the directory and the fixed rate polling period is taken from properties file.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="batchFilesStock" directory="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('qlacceleratorcore.batch.impex.stockbasefolder')}"
    filename-regex="^(\d+)\-(.*).csv" comparator="fileOrderComparator" prevent-duplicates="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('pollerperiod')}"/>                            
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I like to take the fixed-rate value from the database or else the value should be configurable during runtime. I have searched many links and not able to figure out the solution. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sample app https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/dynamic-poller that shows how to use a poller that has a configurable polling rate.

Note that the changes take effect at the next poll...

"When changing the polling period, the change to the trigger will occur after the NEXT poll at the current rate. Therefore, if the current polling period is 60 seconds and you change it to 1 second, it can take up to 60 seconds to take effect, depending on when in the polling cycle you make the change."

In essence, you create a custom trigger that returns an appropriate value when the scheduler invokes `nextExecutionTime()`.

EDIT:

A comment below asks how "...a custom trigger can be used in multiple pollers".

Well, take a look at `nextExecutionTime()`. Notice that the state for a particular poller is contained in an argument passed to the method (`TriggerContext`), which is used to calculate the next execution time.

So, you can simply reuse the trigger in as many pollers as you want...

```
<bean id="myTrigger" class="..." />

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fi1" ... >
    <poller ... trigger="myTrigger" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fi2" ... >
    <poller ... trigger="myTrigger" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

If you want a different rate for each, then simply use a different trigger for each (configured appropriately).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have gone through this link before. But I am not sure how this poller will be linked to 2 different <file:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: My previous comment was not clear so adding comment again. Thanks for the link. I have gone through this link before. But I am not able to understand how this poller will be linked to 2 different <file:inbound-channel-adapter>. I have in my scenario 2 different folders(1 for price and 2 for stock) being polled with different polling period of 10 and 15 mins.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain this.

Comment: sorry I didn't read the note, I just read the link of dynamicpoller. On figuring the solution, I went through the answer again and I have missed your notes and I have to implement the custom trigger thanks.